# Does Streaming a WCF Soap Help the Client Send Using Less Memory?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5, buffering

I have a windows mobile application that sends data via WCF to a server.

The data it sends sometimes exceeds the limit on the windows mobile device.  I am wondering if streaming would help not need to hold all the data I must send in memory at once.

Here is a simple example:

```
[DataContract]
public class MainContract
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid  ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<SubContract> SubContract { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SubContract
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ImageCaption { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Byte[] ImageAsBytes { get; set; }
}
```

Say I have only 1 `MainContract` object.  But it has a lot of `SubContract` objects in it.  (My real scenario is more compelex).

Holding all of `MainContract` in memory is too much for the client side to do.

Will streaming allow me to send send the data over the wire in pieces?  Or do I still have to buffer it all on the client side and the streaming just helps with the receiving of large data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if your method accepts a `MainContract` you will need to have that completely in memory on the client side in order to stream the serialized result to the WCF host.

If loading up a full `MainContract` will take too much memory on the client side, I would adjust the service to allow for something like this:

```
public Guid CreateMainContract(MainContract obj); // return unique id
public Guid CreateSubContract(Guid mainContractToAddTo, SubContract obj);
```

and then modify the calling code to pseduo-stream the data to the WCF host, by means of calling the above operations in a loop. (Obviously, you'll need to change it up for update/delete situations, etc).